# Vertica Logistic Regression prediction: input column is not available

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, vertica

I'm trying to build a logistic regression model following the syntax of  the [built in functions in vertica](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/#Authoring/MachineLearning/LogisticRegression/LogisticRegression.htm%3FTocPath%3DAnalyzing%2520Data%7CMachine%2520Learning%2520for%2520Predictive%2520Analytics%7CMachine%2520Learning%2520for%2520Predictive%2520Analytics%2520Learning%2520Algorithms%7CLogistic%2520Regression%7C_____0). The model builds properly but `predictLogisticReg` does not work.

I am able to build a model using

```
SELECT 
    v_ml.logisticReg('logRegModel', 'public.regression_training_table', 
          'longTermPlayer', ' IOS_or_not, firstDayTransactions',
          '--epsilon=0.000001 --max_iterations=100');
```

and can verify that it has worked by checking the summary:

```
SELECT
    v_ml.summaryLogisticReg(using parameters 
               model_name='logRegModel', owner='dbadmin');
```

When I try to predict features using

```
 SELECT 
     user_id, 
     v_ml.predictLogisticReg('IOS_or_not', 'firstDayTransactions'
            using parameters model_name='logRegModel', owner='dbadmin')
 FROM public.regression_test_table
```

on a test set (with identical columns), I am getting the error:

```
The input column corresponding to "ios_or_not" is not available
```

If you have any idea why it doesn't seem to be recognising the data in the test set I'd very much appreciate it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. For those interested:
I passed the fields within inverted commas, while they should not have been. Replace with

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    v_ml.predictLogisticReg(IOS_or_not, firstDayTransactions
        using parameters model_name='logRegModel', owner='dbadmin')
 FROM public.regression_test_table
```